# Passing different values from an array to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array with different values in state within my component.

I want to dynamically render different sections of an array to the same component but on different pages of my react app.

i.e Pass props down to Component that renders the first title of the array on one page but then render the second title on another page.

Can anyone help?

```
import React from 'react';
import ChartItem from './chart-item.component.js'
import Popup from './modal/index.js'

//styles
import './chart-slides.styles.css'

class Chart extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      sections: [
        {
          title: 'How do you compare to the competition?',
          id: 'chart1',
          iframeUrl: 'https://app.chattermill.io/c/f4a52535-b2b9-4d71-9ac7-e198c9452e3f?compact=true'
        },
        {
          title: 'Main drivers of positive sentiment sentiment are brand, service, and app exeprience. While bugs and security features are big drivers of negative sentiment',
          id: 'chart2',
          iframeUrl: 'https://app.chattermill.io/c/f4a52535-b2b9-4d71-9ac7-e198c9452e3f?compact=true'
        },
        {
          title: 'Scroll through the feedback to see the pain points for customers',
          id: 'chart3',
          iframeUrl: 'https://app.chattermill.io/c/f4a52535-b2b9-4d71-9ac7-e198c9452e3f?compact=true'
        }
      ]
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.sections.map(({ id, title, iframeUrl }) => (
          <ChartItem key={id} title={title} url={iframeUrl} />
        ))}
        <Popup/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Chart;
```

How can I only render the first section from my array in this component below? The component below will be showed in multiple pages within the app.

```
import React from 'react';
import Popup from '../modal/index.js'
import { Heading } from 'rebass'
import './chart-slides.styles.css'
import Iframe from 'react-iframe'

const ChartItem = ({ title, iframeUrl, id }) => (
  <div>
    <a className="demo-btn" id="demo-btn-chart1" href="https://app.hubspot.com/meetings/jack123/presentation" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> Book Demo</a>
      <Heading fontSize="2.8vh" textColor="secondary" className="mobile-chart-title" as='h1'>
        {title}
      </Heading>
      <Iframe
        url={iframeUrl}
        className="iframe-container"
      />
  </div>
);

export default ChartItem
```

Comment: Any reason why `sections` is a state?

Comment: What is the purpose of what you trying to achieve? If you want to render one section don't map all section, only the one you need.

Comment: @DennisVash - could you elaborate how you would map only part of an array? Would this be done by a slice or filter function?

I'm looking to have one array with my data that I pass on to same component but with different elements from array in different sections of my app. 

I plan to have the data being uploaded in real time with API in future.

Comment: You should explain it in the question body, and yes you can filter and then map